# Perl - DNS lookup using Socket and a specific DNS server

Tags: perl, sockets, dns

I use the Socket module to do DNS lookups with Perl. The Socket module uses whichever DNS server the system it runs on is using. Is there a way to force the Socket module use a different DNS server?

I know there are other modules such as "Net::DNS::Resolver", but I'd like to use core Perl modules for this.

Thank you

Comment: What happened when you sent DNS queries via UDP to the DNS server of your choice?

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own DNS client or "shell out" to an external tool. Otherwise, there's no way to do DNS lookups with just core Perl<sup>[1]</sup>, much less querying specific servers.

---

1. There are some functions that can end up doing DNS lookups some of the time as part of a larger name-resolution system (e.g. `inet_aton`).

Comment: You can do DNS lookups using the core Socket module in Perl. I just don't know if there is a way to force it to use a different DNS server from the one used by the system on which the script runs.

Comment: No, there's no function that does DNS lookups in Socket. There are functions that resolve names (e.g. `inet_aton`) that *may* result in a DNS call, but that's not the same thing. For example, most systems have a host file that's consulted first when you asked the system to resolve a name.

Comment: I get the job done (get hostname for ip and ip for hostname) with Socket module alone if that makes it easy to understand my point..... Thank you

Comment: No, you don't, which is why you're asking how to do it. You don't want to get hostname for ip and ip for hostname, you want to ask a specific DNS server to resolve a hostname using core Perl. And to that, I answer: core Perl doesn't include anything that talks to DNS servers.